# Is it possible the knockout ignores 'data-bind=with..." ?

Tags: knockout.js

Please take a look at the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form data-bind="with: selectedMerchant">
        <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
        <button data-bind="click: show"> SHOW </button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function PartnersViewModel() {
            self.selectedMerchant = ko.observable({'name': 'John'});
            self.show = function() {
                alert(JSON.stringify(self.selectedMerchant()));
            }
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new PartnersViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the line:

```
<form data-bind="with: selectedMerchant">
```

makes the object 'selectedMerchant' the binding context of the form. That's why inside the 'h1'-tag, we'll see the name 'John'.

However, the line:

```
<button data-bind="click: show"> SHOW </button>
```

says (as I understand) that once the button is clicked, the method "show" **inside** the object 'selectedMerchant' will be invoked. Of course this method doesn't exist inside selectedMerchant, so I expect to see an Error.

To my surprise, it works correctly and I get a pop-up window saying:

> {'name': 'John'}

I don't understand why knockout.js invokes a method which is outside the object 'selectedMerchant'. Does anyone have a good explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `var self = this;` from the beginning of your view model declaration.

Without declaring `self` the line `self.show = function() { ...` declares a global `show` function on the `window` object that is why KO can find this handler.

So with properly declaring `self` your code will give the expected error: `Message: show is not defined`

```
<script>
    function PartnersViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.selectedMerchant = ko.observable({'name': 'John'});
        self.show = function() {
            alert(JSON.stringify(self.selectedMerchant()));
        }
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new PartnersViewModel());
</script>
```